# Installing Emacs on x86 Ubuntu Make error

Tags: ubuntu, emacs

After running ./configure the installation guide tells me to run make

```
xargon@N130:~/Downloads/emacs-21.4$ make
if [ ! -f /home/xargon/Downloads/emacs-21.4/lisp/abbrev.elc ]; then \
  make  bootstrap; \
fi
cd lib-src; make all  \
  CC='gcc' CFLAGS='-g -O2' CPPFLAGS='-D_BSD_SOURCE  ' \
  LDFLAGS='' MAKE='make'
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/xargon/Downloads/emacs-21.4/lib-src'
Makefile:135: *** recipe commences before first target. Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/xargon/Downloads/emacs-21.4/lib-src'
Makefile:263: recipe for target 'lib-src' failed
make: *** [lib-src] Error 2
```

Not sure what to make of this!

Comment: why are you building such an old version (~2005)?

Comment: I do not know :D